# Replace missing input data with a "0" in ouput csv/txt with Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, replace

I have a GIS input file that contains hundreds of the following lines (objects):

```
{
    POSITION="[950.28174, 797.89899]";
    TYPE="Saltlake";
    AZIMUT="-25.722504";
    PARENT="";
};

    {
    POSITION="[900.71307, 777.2226, -3.8146973]";
    TYPE="Oak";
    AZIMUT="-168.15758";
    PARENT="";
};
```

**POSITION** means length, width, height [x,y,z]. Currently I use this powershell script to convert the input for the next tool:

```
$d=gc input.txt   
$rows=@()   
for ($i=0; $i -le $d.count -2; ++$i) {                                          
if( $d[$i] -match "POSITION" ) { 
 $pos = $d[$i].Replace('POSITION="[', '').Replace(',',';').Replace(']";','').Replace(' ', '').trim()  
 $typ = $d[$i+1].Replace('TYPE=', '').Replace(';', '').Replace(' ', '').trim() 
 $ori = $d[$i+2].Replace('AZIMUT="', '').Replace('"', '').Replace('PARENT=;', '').Replace(' ', '').trim() 
 $rows += $("{0};{1};{2}" -f $typ,$pos,$ori)            
} 
}

sc -path output.csv -value $rows
```

The output.txt looks like this:

```
"Saltlake";950.28174;797.89899;-25.722504;
"Oak";900.71307;777.2226;-3.8146973e-006;-168.15758;
```

What happens is that the next conversion tool mistakes the AZIMUT value of "Saltlake" for its Z-Position, as there was no input given after the y-value in POSITION of input.txt - unlike for "Oak".

**Now, is it possible to replace that missing Z-input space with a "0" and of course, don't replace it if a Z-Position is given?**

The aim is to make output.txt look like this:

```
 "Saltlake";950.28174;797.89899;0;-25.722504;
 "Oak";900.71307;777.2226;-3.8146973e-006;-168.15758;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added one line to make this work. I use the `-split` operator to check how many parts there are in the POSITION (by splitting on the separator `;`). If that equals two, it means the zero has to be added, and otherwise not.

```
$d=gc .\tmp.txt
$rows=@()   
for ($i=0; $i -le $d.count -2; ++$i) {                                          
    if( $d[$i] -match "POSITION" ) { 
        $pos = $d[$i].Replace('POSITION="[', '').Replace(',',';').Replace(']";','').Replace(' ', '').trim()
        if (($pos -split ';').count -eq 2) {$pos += ";0"}
        $typ = $d[$i+1].Replace('TYPE=', '').Replace(';', '').Replace(' ', '').trim() 
        $ori = $d[$i+2].Replace('AZIMUT="', '').Replace('"', '').Replace('PARENT=;', '').Replace(' ', '').trim() 
        $rows += $("{0};{1};{2}" -f $typ,$pos,$ori)            
    } 
}
$rows
```